# .Net WebBrowser Control encapsulating anything else but IE?

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control

We're using SHDocVw.dll for providing a web browser control to some of our users that access our system through a gadget they install on their computers. Now, that control encapsulates IE. Anyone knows of ways to let the users choose what browser to encapsulate?

EDIT - Clarifying: I'm interested in being able to encapsulate another browser. Not necessarily doing it with SHDocVw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a active x control for FireFox, so you could encapsulate that as well.  Its not clear how well the XULRunners active x control supports IWebBrowser2 interface (note that xul runners says the active x is not complete.)

see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner/What_XULRunner_Provides
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XULRunner
http://nick.typepad.com/blog/2008/03/can-mozilla-be.html
http://www.iol.ie/~locka/mozilla/control.htm

In short it will be a lot of work.

Comment: Ah, some traction! Thanks, I'll investigate this some.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change which browser SHDocVw encapsulates. Sorry. SHDocVw is part of IE, it does not host IE. [See this MSDN article for the IE architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741313(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks. +1. I actually knew that SHDocVw wasn't the way. =) Clarified my question now.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to skip the web browser control completely and just start a new process running the browser that you do want.  Here is a basic and simple example of how you would launch a firefox browser:

```
Dim p As New Process()
p.StartInfo.FileName = "firefox.exe" 
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "http://stackoverflow.com" 
p.Start()
```